# Java Process InputStream in Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, inputstream

I'm using Java Process as below :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

        response = IOUtils.toString(pr.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        response = response.substring(2, response.length()-4);
        logger.debug("response :" + response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can see the loggers in my local machine(Mac OSX). But when I run the same program in a Redhat Linux machine, I'm having problem seeing the logs. I don't have any clue whats happening after **pr.getInputStream()**. Having a logger before that statement is working fine. I want to see the response of the **exec(cmd)**. How can I achieve this. I suspect something is wrong when I'm trying to read the InputStream.

Comment: I suggest you read the getErrorStream() as well as I bet your command it reporting an error.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is there a way to check if my exec command is returning a error/success. So that I can read my response accordingly.

Comment: @SatishJonnala In which sense? The docs for `Runtime` seem to be helpful if `exec` itself fails, and the docs for `Process` might help if the command you are running fails.

Comment: @DennisMeng My exec command is successful. I can see the result of its execution. The shell is supposed to give some response after the execution. The only problem is, my program halts while trying to read the Process InputStream. I suspect if the exec is waiting on me to provide more input, or do I need to close any of the open streams/channels. I'm completely new to CLI from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading input stream and error stream in two threads other than the one that launched the process.
I have seen processes gets stuck writing to error or output streams if no one is reading what they are writing.